# Proper Receiving and Handling of Holy Books

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, books-generally

I ordered the Mordechai Breuer edition of the Tanach (Aleppo) and I want to know the proper Jewish way to receive the Holy Book (initial purification and consecration of the object) and then ensure proper handling of it there after when reading it.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification... I was definitely thinking in the context of a Torah Scroll so was going a bit overboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper respect for Jewish Holy books, as documented in Jewish Law:

- Holy Books are always placed right side up; not upside down. They need to be turned right-side up, if found otherwise.
- Holy Books are not to be placed - when open - on their print.(A popular way to *keep the place* when the book is open.)
- One does not place Holy Books inside other books as a bookmark.
- One may not use Holy Books for one's benefit, such as to create shade, or to hide what one is doing, or to lift up other [secular] books to a more comfortable height.
- One does not use Holy Books as a place to safeguard [unrelated] papers and documents.
- One should not put paper/books on Holy Books while writing in them, unless it's related to the subject at hand.
- Holy Books are not to be thrown.
- Holy Books are not to be brought into the bathroom, lavatory or  bedroom where marital relations take place, unless double-covered (like in 2 bags).
- One does not urinate nor relieve oneself nor have marital relations in the presence of Holy Books, unless they are double-covered.
- One does not place Holy Books on the bench one sits on. Or: One does not sit on a bench that has Holy Books on them. If the Holy Books are on something else (like secular books) and are 2.5" above the height of the bench, one can sit on that bench.
- One does not put Holy Books on the floor.
- One should not put a Holy Book on one's lap and then lean one's elbows on it.
- Except in emergency, one should not sit on a box which have Holy Books inside.
- On does not pile up secular books on top of Holy Books. (Some types of Holy Books have to be put on top of others, not under them. Not relevant, as you only have one Holy Book.)
- Even after they are worn out, Holy Books cannot be burned or thrown away. They need to be put in Geniza (found in most synagogues.)

Sources (Please excuse the Hebrew, the translations are above):

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 150](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0149_L2):6

> בַּיִת שֶׁיֵשׁ בּוֹ סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה, אָסוּר לְשַׁמֵּשׁ שָׁם, אֶלָּא צָרִיךְ שֶׁיּוֹצִיאוֹ לְחֶדֶר אַחֵר. וְאִם אֵין לוֹ חֶדֶר אַחֵר, יַעֲשֶׂה לְפָנָיו מְחִיצָה גְבוֹהָה עֲשָׂרָה טְפָחִים. וּתְהֵא מְחִיצָה סְתוּמָה, שֶלֹּא יֵרָאֶה סֵפֶר הַתּוֹרָה. וְהַיְרִיעָה שֶסְּבִיב הַמִּטָּה לָא חֲשִׁיבָה מְחִצָּה, כֵּיוָן שֶהִיא נָדָה, אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן קָשַׁר אוֹתָהּ מִלְּמַטָה (וְעַיֵּן לְעֵיל סִימָן פ סָעִיף עו). וּבִתְפִלִּין וְחֻמָּשִׁים וּשְׁאָר כִּתְבֵי הַקֹּדֶשׁ, כְּגוֹן גְמָרָא וּמִדְרָשִׁים וּמְפָרְשֵׁיהֶם, בֵּין שֶׁהֵם בִּכְתָב בֵּין שֶׁהֵם בִּדְפוּס, יָכוֹל לְהַנִּיחָן בּכְלִי תּוֹךְ כֶּלִי. וְדַוְקָא כְּשֶׁהַכְּלִי הַשֵּׁנִי אֵינוֹ מְיֻחָד לָהֶם. אֲבָל כֵּלִים הַמְיֻחָדִים לָהֶם, אֲפִלוּ הֵם עֲשַׂרָה, כֻלָּם כְּחַד חֲשִׁיבֵי. וְאִם פָּרַשׁ אֵיזֶה מִכְסֶה עַל הָאַרְגָּז שֶׁהַסְּפָרִים בּוֹ, חָשׁוּב כִכְלִי בְּתוֹךְ כֶּלִי. ‏

[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 28](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0027_L2):4-7,9

> אֲפִלּוּ שְׁאָר סִפְרֵי קֹדֶשׁ אִם מֻנָּחִים עַל סַפְסָל, אָסוּר לֵישֵׁב עַל סַפְסָל זֶה, אֶלָּא אִם הַסְּפָרִים מֻנָּחִים, עַל אֵיזֶה דָּבָר שֶׁגָּבוֹהַּ לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת טֶפַח, וּמִכָּל שֶׁכֵּן דְּאָסוּר לְהַנִּיחַ סְפָרִים עַל גַּבֵּי קַרְקַע. לֹא יַנִּיחַ אָדָם סֵפֶר עַל בִּרְכָּיו, וּשְׁנֵי אַצִילֵי, יָדָיו עָלָיו. בִּשְׁעַת הַדְּחַק מֻתָּר לֵישֵׁב עַל גַּבֵּי תֵבָה שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ שְׁאָר סִפְרֵי קֹדֶשׁ. אֲבָל אִם יֵשׁ בָּהּ סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה אָסוּר. מַנִּיחִים חֻמָּשִׁים עַל גַּבֵּי נְבִיאִים וכְתוּבִים, וְכֵן כְּתוּבִים עַל גַּבֵּי נְבִיאִים, וּנְבִיאִים עַל גַּבֵּי כְּתוּבִים. אֲבָל אֵין מַנִּיחִין נְבִיאִים וּכְתוּבִים, עַל גַּבֵּי חֻמָּשִׁים. ‏
>
> סֵפֶר תּוֹרָה שֶׁבָּלָה, גּוֹנְזִין אוֹתוֹ. וְכֵן שְׁאָר סְפָרִים וְכִתְבֵי קֹדֶשׁ וְתַשְׁמִישֵׁי קְדֻשָּׁה. וְאָסוּר לְשָׂרְפָן (עַיֵּן שו"ע אוֹרַח חַיִּים סִימָן קנ"ד). ‏
>
> אֵין זוֹרְקִין כִּתְבֵי קֹדֶשׁ, וַאֲפִלּוּ הֲלָכוֹת וְאַגָּדוֹת, וְאָסוּר לַהֲפֹךְ אוֹתָן עַל פְּנֵיהֶם. וְאִם מְצָאָן הֲפוּכִין צָרִיךְ לְהַנִּיחָן כָּרָאוּי (יו"ד סִימָן רפ"ב). ‏
>
> אֵין לְהַשְׁתִּין מַיִם בִּפְנֵי סְפָרִים, וּלְעֵת הַצֹּרֶךְ, עַל כָּל פָּנִים יִהְיוּ מֻנָּחִים גְּבוֹהִים עֲשָׂרָה טְפָחִים (כלל ל"א).‏
>
> אָסוּר לְהִשְׁתַּמֵּשׁ בְּסֵפֶר לַהֲנָאָתוֹ, כְּגוֹן לְהַעֲמִידוֹ לְהָגֵן מִפְּנֵי הַחַמָּה, אוֹ כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא יִרְאֶה חֲבֵרוֹ מַה שֶּׁהוּא עוֹשֶׂה. אֲבָל אִם הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ זוֹרַחַת עַל הַסֵּפֶר שֶׁהוּא לוֹמֵד בּוֹ, מֻתָּר לְהָגֵן בְּסֵפֶר אַחֵר כֵּיוָן שֶׁאֵינוֹ עוֹשֶׂה לַהֲנָאָתוֹ. וְכֵן לְהַנִּיחַ סֵפֶר תַּחַת סֵפֶר שֶׁהָיָה לוֹמֵד בּוֹ, כְּדֵי לְהַגְבִּיהוֹ לְצֹרֶךְ הַלִּמּוּד, יֵשׁ לְהַתִּיר. אֲבָל אֵין לְהַנִּיחַ סֵפֶר בְּתוֹךְ סֵפֶר אַחֵר, שֶׁלֹּא יִצְטָרֵךְ לְחַפֵּשׂ אַחַר כָּךְ מְקוֹם לִמּוּדוֹ. לֹא יְשַׂרְטֵט אֵיזֶה קֻנְטְרֵס עַל הַסֵּפֶר, לְפִי שֶׁאֵין קְדֻשָּׁה בְּקֻנְטְרֵס, עַד שֶׁיִּכְתְּבוּ בּוֹ. וְכֵן לֹא יַנִּיחַ נְיָר וְכַדּוֹמֶה בַּסֵּפֶר, לְמִשְׁמֶרֶת (מ"א סִימָן קנ"ד פת"ש ביו"ד ס"ס רפ"ב) ‏

Comment: "One may not use Holy Books for one's benefit, such as to ... lift up other books to a more comfortable height." This doesn't match with the source. "וְכֵן לְהַנִּיחַ סֵפֶר תַּחַת סֵפֶר שֶׁהָיָה לוֹמֵד בּוֹ, כְּדֵי לְהַגְבִּיהוֹ לְצֹרֶךְ הַלִּמּוּד, יֵשׁ לְהַתִּיר."

Comment: @Scimonster  - 1. Thanks for the edit. 2. This was written for the OP who owns only 1 H.B. Your quote is about using one H.B. when learning another H.B. and implies what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you very much Danny Schoemann! This was perfect and I appreciate the Hebrew sources (I have saved them).